# Можно ли получить X509Certificate из .sig файла?

Tags: java, spring-security, криптопро

Пытаюсь вытащить X509Certificate из файла подписи .sig чтобы эту подпись проверить. Как корректно это сделать?

Пытался вот так:

```html
InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesSignature);
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
```

но на этапе генерации сертификата вылетает с ошибкой `"Unable to initialize, java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length"`

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось получить сертификат, но я не до конца понимаю что я сделал.

Вот код:

```html
        final Asn1BerDecodeBuffer asnBuf = new Asn1BerDecodeBuffer(bytesSignature);
        Asn1BerEncodeBuffer encBuf = new Asn1BerEncodeBuffer();
        final ContentInfo all = new ContentInfo();
        try {
            all.decode(asnBuf);
        } catch (Asn1Exception e) {
            throw  new CertificateException();
        }

        final SignedData cms = (SignedData) all.content;

        final Certificate[] certificates = new Certificate[cms.certificates.elements.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < (cms.certificates.elements.length); i++) {
            try {
                cms.certificates.elements[i].encode(encBuf);
            } catch (Asn1Exception e) {
                throw new CertificateException();
            }
            final CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            final Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(encBuf.getInputStream());
            certificates[i] = cert;
        }
        if (certificates.length > 0 ) {
            return (X509Certificate) certificates[0];

        } else throw new CertificateException("Не удалось получить сертификат из подписи.");
```